# Python plot data as a function of angle in a ring

Tags: python, matplotlib

How would I have to proceed to obtain the following plot in Python :

[image: polar_plot]

For each angle I have a given value and I would like to plot it in a ring, any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative approach would be to create a [`pcolormesh`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh) inside a set of polar axes:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def polar_heat(values, thetas=None, radii=None, ax=None, fraction=0.3,
               **kwargs):

    values = np.atleast_2d(values)
    if thetas is None:
        thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, values.shape[1]).reshape(1, -1)
    if radii is None:
        radii = np.linspace(0, 1, values.shape[0] + 1).reshape(-1, 1)
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, subplot_kw={'polar':True})

    mesh = ax.pcolormesh(thetas, radii, values, **kwargs)

    radrange = radii.ptp()
    ax.set_rlim(radrange * (1 - 1. / fraction), radrange)
    ax.set_axis_off()

    return mesh
```

For example:

```
thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 180)
values = np.sin(6 * thetas)

polar_heat(values, thetas, fraction=0.3)
```

[image]

You could easily have multiple nested rings:

```
values2 = np.vstack([np.sin(3 * thetas), np.cos(6 * thetas)])
polar_heat(values2, fraction=0.6)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Something along these lines might work for you

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Wedge

import numpy as np

theta = np.linspace(0, 360, 100)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon=False)
for i in range(len(theta)-1):
    ax.add_artist(
        Wedge((0, 0), 1, theta[i], theta[i+1], width=0.2, color=str(np.random.rand()))
)
ax.set_xlim((-2,2))
ax.set_ylim((-2,2))
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I would wrap that up in a function, but yes

Comment: You can also use the normalization and color map functionality in `mpl.cm` to get RGBA values for each of the wedges

Comment: and you probably want to use a `PatchCollection`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `pie` function from `matplotlib.pyplot`.

You can plot a standard pie chart and place a white circle in the center then, so that it looks like a donut diagram.
See [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@krishnakummar/donut-chart-with-python-matplotlib-d411033c960b#.3vce96jmp) for an example of what I'm talking about.

You can also experiment with Vega (format for visualization), namely with `Vincent` library for Python. See examples with pie/donut charts [here](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/charts_library.html).